# Linear Regression - Data Subset with Lowest Mean-Squared Error?

Tags: regression, linear-model, ranking, subset

**Short version:** given a linear regression dataset and an integer $K$, what data subset of size $K$ results in linear parameters with the lowest mean squared error on the entire dataset?

**Long version:** Suppose I have a supervised dataset $D_n := \{x_n, y_n\}_{n=1}^N$ and I want to perform ordinary linear regression by minimizing

$$ L_{OLS, N}(w) = ||Y_N - X_N w||_2^2$$

where $Y_N$ is the matrix formed by stacking $y_n$ as row vectors and $X_N$ is the matrix formed by stacking $x_n$ as row vectors. I use the subscript $N$ to remind us that we used all the data to compute the parameter estimates.  Alternatively, I might want to perform ridge linear regression by minimizing

$$ L_{Ridge, N}(w) = ||Y_N - X_N w||_2^2 + c ||w||_2^2$$

We know that the parameters that minimize the above losses are given by

$$w_{OLS, N} = (X_N^T X_N)^{-1} X_N^T Y_N$$

$$w_{Ridge, N} = (X_N^T X_N + c I)^{-1} X_N^T Y_N$$

What I'm curious to know is: if we're  forced to choose a subset of only $K < N$ data $D_K := \{(x_k, y_k)\}_{k=1}^K \subset D_N$ and we fit parameters

$$w_{OLS, K} = (X_K^T X_K)^{-1} X_K^T Y_K$$

$$w_{Ridge, K} = (X_K^T X_K + c I)^{-1} X_K^T Y_K$$

what subset of $K$ data results in parameters $w_{OLS, K}$ and $w_{Ridge, K}$ such that $L_{OLS, N}(w)$ and $L_{Ridge, N}(w)$ (respectively) are minimized?

Answer (score 0):

the squared error of the full data set are: $$SSE=\varepsilon'\varepsilon$$where $\varepsilon=Y-X\hat\beta_K$ and $\hat\beta_K=(X_K'X_K)^{-1}X'_KY_K$

You want to minimize SSE wrt a subset K. Unfortunately the only way to do it is through trying all combinations of K-subsets. It's $\frac{N!}{K!(N-K)!}$, which is a lot of work to say the least.

Comment: One place to watch out when you try this is if two observations have the same $x$-values but different $y$-values.

Comment: In my setup, I don't get to choose the number of observations. That's a given parameter, and it could be less than the number of effective parameters.

Comment: No, not true. You'll get zero errors on those $K$ points, but I want to know about the errors on the full dataset.

Comment: Now that I think about it more, I think the above answer isn't correct even when there are more observations than effective number of parameters.

Comment: Suppose $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and I choose the 3 biggest outliers. You'll get some parameters that will have terrible performance on the full dataset.

Comment: I feel like leverage should be relevant somehow...

Comment: This answer is spot on. Of course you may be able to find an optimal subset *in specific circumstances*, but in general, there is no better algorithm that is *guaranteed* to give you the optimal subset in general. Also, regarding the three biggest outliers: these can just as easily be the optimal subset. Some simulation (randomly generating $N$ data points, doing exhaustive search and checking whether the result includes extremal points - feasible for small $N$) will turn up an example.

Comment: To clarify, is there a proof that no algorithm exists, or is your statement an assertion?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer, no proof, but I'm sure it's the case. there could be search algorithms that lead to high probability of finding a good solution, but I can't think of one. my confidence is due to the problem being discrete. finding optimal $\hat\beta$ is a continuous problem, while finding a subset K is discrete. these type of problems end up with permutation type of solutions

Comment: I'm okay with random algorithms :)

Comment: @Aksakal I do want to point out that optimizing a continuous quantity over a discrete space doesn't mean the best solution is the worst case solution e.g. the 0-1 knapsack problem. Your conjecture may be true, but it is a conjecture, not an answer

Comment: We’re optimizing the discrete quantity here, @RylanSchaeffer . There’s a finite number of errors sums, one for each subset K. When you’re optimizing beta then it’s continuous. You’re right that my answer is a conjecture, but conjecture is an answer too. We don’t discriminate answers here

Comment: I found Mahoney 2011's "Randomized algorithms for matrices and data" which gives a randomized algorithm with high probability of recovering the correct answer

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer great news, did they prove my conjecture? 